# How to get DomPdf to work with CakePHP and Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, dompdf

*Using CakePHP 2.6.7*

I have been working successfully with CakePHP and Bootstrap for a while. However, now I need to be able to generate a web page and then convert it to a PDF. I've looked at [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) but that doesn't allow external stylesheets.

Finally, I found [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) which looked promising. But the PDF still isn't correct. Bits of content lie on top of each other and some things are stretched across the page etc.

I can't work out if it is due to CakePHP interfering with the requests for the stylesheets or whether DomPDF cannot handle the CSS used by Bootstrap.

I also tried copying the source of [google.co.uk](https://www.google.co.uk/) to generate a PDF but the Google logo and buttons from the top left are missing (the search box and buttons appear though).

Can anyone explain why this might not be working?

Comment: While the goal of dompdf is to provide browser-class rendering of HTML content the project isn't there yet. More than likely the issue is that dompdf isn't quite able to parse your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's css would be too complicated for any html to pdf library to parse. Keep your html for pdf generation simple.

Use the [CakePDF](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf) plugin for generating PDFs with CakePHP.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that might be an issue, I've just tried using wkhtmltopdf from command line and that handles bootstrap's css quite well (not perfect but pretty close). I see there appears to be something about using wkhtmltopdf with that plugin so will look into that. Thank you.

Comment: That's probably the best answer ... use a headless browser like wkhtmltopdf or PhantomJS.